# Weird pause between image appearing (and fading)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

The code is this:

```
if (event.pageX < 50) {
        mozog = false;
        kepindex++;
        if (kepindex > 1) kepindex = 0;
        $("#gol img").fadeTo(200, 0.0, function() {
            $("#gol img").attr('src', kepek[kepindex]);
            $("#gol img").css('left', '200px');
            $("#gol img").fadeTo(200, 1);
        });

    }
```

The problem is:

- next image appears usually after a 3-4 second pause
- sometimes the new image blinks before apperaing well
- and sometimes the "new" image remains the previous img.

I can't understand.

Very thanks for any idea.

Comment: Are you preloading the images?

Comment: @ezanker:  No.  Could it take affect that problems?

Comment: If you want smooth fading between images, you should preload all the images so the browser does not need to make a trip to the server.

Comment: @ezanker: Thank you, I will do it.
What technic do you admit for this?

Comment: https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/ the second one at this link is probably fine.